# How do I check if smartd and mdadm are running correctly?

Tags: raid, debian-squeeze, mdadm, smart

I have a raid system on debian:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB,...
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        2432    19535008+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2            2433        2918     3903795   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3            2919       38913   289129837+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 320.1 GB, ...
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1        2432    19535008+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2            2433        2918     3903795   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3            2919       38913   289129837+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

# df -h 
/dev/md0               19G   12G  6,0G  66% /      type ext3 (rw)
/dev/md2              272G  245G   25G  91% /var   type ext3 (rw)
```

I would like to check if everything is running fine and configure it, so I will get an email if any error occurs.

---

the only line in my `/etc/smartd.conf` is:

`DEVICESCAN -d removable -n standby -m root -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner`

will that scan those 2 raid devices?

And in my `/etc/cron.d/mdadm` there is this line:
`57 0 * * 0 root if [ -x /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray ] && [ $(date +\%d) -le 7 ]; then /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray --cron --all --idle --quiet; fi`

in `/usr/share/mdadm/checkarray` it sais: it initiates a check run of an MD array's redundancy information

Answer (score 3):

If you want to monitor reliability of hard disks install `smartmontools` package which provides utilities to check hard disks for disk degradation and failure, using the Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology System (SMART) built into most modern ATA and SCSI hard disks.

The package contains `smartctl` tool which is useful for checking hard disks from command line and `smartd` daemon that checks hard disks at a specified interval and logs warnings/errors to the syslog and can also send warnings and errors to a specified email address.

To enable the daemon, you have  to uncomment the line `start_smart` in the file `/etc/default/smartmontools`. Then, you have to define in the file `/etc/smartd.conf` what hard disks do you want to monitor  and start the service `smartmontools` (check [man smartd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/smartd) and [man smartd.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/smartd.conf) for detailed instructions, further, there are many examples in this file):

```
/dev/sda  -m admin@example.com -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner
/dev/sdb  -m admin@example.com -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner
```

You can monitor your md devices with `mdadm` tool. If you want to receive emails with alerts define a mail recipient in the file `/etc/mdadm.conf` (details in [man mdadm.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/mdadm.conf) and [man mdadm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm)):

```
MAILADDR admin@example.com
```

Then, schedule via cron this command (the schedule period is up to you):

```
mdadm --monitor --scan -1
```

Comment: I added the information on my machine to the question. Do I have to change anything there? How can I check if the services are running and the check is done?

Comment: The word DEVICESCAN will cause any remaining lines in this
configuration file to be ignored: it tells smartd to scan for all
ATA and SCSI devices. Just change -m email option.

Comment: OK.Now only missing a solution how to check,if the services are running correctly.Can I somehow simulate a SMART-failure and a diskcrash in one of the raid?

Comment: The checkarray will run parity checks across all your redundant arrays what is not exactly what you requested. So schedule another batch with mdadm --monitor --scan -1 command.

Comment: Disk failure simulation: mdadm --manage --set-faulty /dev/mdX /dev/sdY, I don't know the structure of your MD devices. SMART error simulation is not easily doable (you will have to create some smartctl wrapper to produce SMART report with some errors).

Comment: Do I have to change that in my /etc/cron.d/mdadm? Or in `/etc/smartd.conf`? Do I leave the line with DEVICESCAN? Whats the difference to checkarray?